# Get attribute values for just selected bar in chart

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

How to get the attribute values of just one bar on a chart when clicked and change its border color? I am using multibar chart

Answer (score 2):

This isn't an option in NVD3, but you can do it yourself:

```
d3.selectAll(".nv-bar").on("click", function(d) {
  d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");
  // d is the current data
  console.log(d);
});
```